# Sharepoint Central Admin not appearing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Good day,

right now, I have installed a Sharepoint Foundation 2013, and just completed setting up everything. unfortunately, I cannot see the central administration.

I have already ran the Configuration Wizard twice, but still the Central Administration does not appear.

[Update, thanks to @Bunzab]

I didn't get any 404 or 500. I only have this:
[image: page displayed by central admin]
and this:
[image: page displayed with source code]

I installed SharePoint Foundation 2013 on Windows 8.0, with instructions [here](http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1) and using `New-SpConfigurationDatabase` with Powershell (instructions from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suhasaraos/archive/2013/04/06/installing-sharepoint-2013-on-a-single-server-without-a-domain-controller-and-using-sql-server-express.aspx))

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get an exception? 404? 500? Did you check IIS to see if the admin site has been created correctly? You will need to add more detail as many things can go wrong.

Comment: @Bunzab updated the question with images/screenshots

Comment: Check the application pool of the central admin

Comment: I found no problem on the IIS/application pool side.  :(